# Split html text after several non-html characters

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am making a website where you can post articles with HTML layout and I want it so when the article reaches a certain amount of chars, I want it to be split up in two pieces.

I first tried to just use subtring, but when an image was posted, it still counted all the base64 characters from the image, so this wasn't an option.

I have been able to trim the input with JQuery `$(message).text()` but I have not found a way to append a split after the several characters then.

This is my code atm:

```js
function MoreButtons() {
    let berichten = document.getElementsByClassName("berichtEerst");
    for (const bericht of berichten) {
        if ($(bericht).text().length > 20) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

This is a preview of a message:

[image: Message preview]

So I wanna implement a way with Javascript or PHP where it puts an 'Read Further' button after x non-html characters

Comment: Could you share an example of  the case you're running into? Create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to check out.

Comment: but I have no idea how to do it so how would I create an example?

Comment: The article I linked to gives you some tools to create one. Up here you have an image of an example message. Showing the HTML of that message will help us know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have found a way to add the "Read more" after 20 character but I don't think it's possible for the images that are nested with the text to still appear, because when we change the value of a span for example, it doesn't select only the text characters inside of it, but the images tags too.

Comment: Yea that's what I was trying to achieve with the picture, I could use php regular expressions maybe but I'm not sure